# How to make an app that works with Amazon account?

Tags: web-applications, login-with-amazon, amazon-marketplace

I want to make an app that gives an user the opportunity to have more advanced history of his sales. I need to know the way I can connect to amazon (through Java app for example). I haven't done anything like that so I just need simple steps just to know what exactly should I search for in Internet.

Comment: Related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506808/is-there-a-amazon-webstore-api-for-customers?rq=1  At the time, there was no API for Amazon store customers.

Comment: Or do you mean your user is an Amazon Marketplace *seller*?

Comment: My user is a seller. He wants to have a different view of his monthly sales and arrange them in certain categories.

Answer (score 1):

I think Amazon launched MWS(Merchat Web Services) for programmatically exchange data on offer listings, orders, payments, reports, and more.
Read more about what is MWS: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/index.html
See it's developer's guide: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/index.html

If you use these APIs you can easily build an android or a web app to provide the customized views and operations on this data.